# GeoServer get native SRS of layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, openlayers

I want to get the native SRS/EPSG-Code of a layer deployed in GeoServer. Maybe similar to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766126/get-the-epsg-code-from-openlayers-3-layer but with Openlayers 2 or the RESTful API of GeoServer.

Is there a way to achieve this?
GeoServer itself displays those native EPSG codes when you look at your layers on the right hand side.

So somehow this must be possible but I just can't find the answer.

Comment: Have you looked in the capabilities response?

Comment: WMS does not define any supported SRS to be native SRS but you could check WFS or WCS capabilities if they are available from the service.

Comment: Well it seems like the WMS is indeed giving the native EPSG in the capabilities. See my proposed answer on this question

Answer (score -1):

Ok I have found a solution that works for me. I hope that this is something that works in every environment but for now I have not tested it somewhere else than on my own GeoServer.

This is the js code:

```
function getEPSG(bboxObject) {
    var bboxObject = JSON.stringify(bboxObject);
    bboxObject = bboxObject.split('"');

    for (var i = 0; i < bboxObject.length; i++) {
        if (bboxObject[i].includes("EPSG")) {
            console.log(bboxObject[i]);
            return bboxObject[i];
        }
    }

    console.log("function getEPSG encountered an error!");
    return "EPSG:4326";
}
```

What you have to do prior to this function is to make a `GetCapabilities` request on your WMS server and find the layer you want to work with. Then extract the `bbox` object and pass it on to this function.
The `bbox` object contains the `boundingbox` in the native SRS and also states the EPSG-Code of it.

But be sure to use the `version=1.1.0` when making the `GetCapabilities` request if you want to work on with that bounding box provided. It seems that `version=1.3.0` switches the coordinates of the box so that this can't be used at all.

Comment: GetCapabilities will have an entry for each supported EPSG for each layer.  Your code will find a supported EPSG, but there may be more than one and there's nothing to indicate which one is the native SRS.

Comment: That's not true. I dont grab the list of supported EPSG (which is nearly everything). Look at the response of such an request. And than look at the boundingbox object (bbox). The bbox is computed when you import the layer into GeoServer from the native EPSG of the data. And this EPSG Code is also stated in the response.

Comment: It must be server dependent.  I'm using     `fetch(url + '&request=GetCapabilities').then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(new ol.format.WMSCapabilities().read(text).Capability.Layer.BoundingBox));
    });` and getting an array containing multiple EPSG codes and extents.

Comment: Same result using the OpenLayers 2 parser except the sort order was different `console.log(JSON.stringify(new OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities().read(text).capability.layers[0].bbox));`  Note that to get SRS/CRS from WMS 1.3.0 you may need to specify `new OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities({version: '1.3.0'})`

Comment: Please look here what I mean. If you make the request and than loop to the specific layer you are working with, this is the response and that is where you get the EPSG from: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmf5X.png

Comment: That's great when your service only returns one entry in bbox.  I'm getting mine from the same place and it doesn't help if the service returns 8 entries and what I know to be the native SRS is entry 7.